# Css only vertical timeline

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a vertical timeline with css, can any one help. left portion is getting congested. left portion pointer circle is overlapped with opposite one.
Trying to make it with css only. Is there any java-script we can add to make it work.

http://jsfiddle.net/cdtHx/

Code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <style type='text/css'>
.line {
    width:930px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.line div {
    width: 408px;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    border:solid 1px #B4BBCD;
    min-height:35px;
    text-align:justify;
    word-wrap:break-word;
    list-style:none;
}
.ci {
    position:relative;
    float:right;
}
.cl {
    position: relative;
    text-align:right;
}
.ci, .cl span {
    padding:10px;
}
.line:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
}
.ci:before, .cl:after, .ci span:before, .cl span:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.line:before {
    width: 3px;
    top: -20px;
    bottom: -20px;
    background:#000;
}
.ci:before {
    width: 5px;
    height: 5px;
    border: 3px solid #CCC;
    border-radius: 100px;
    margin: 10px 0 0 -38px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2), inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    background: #000;
}
.ci:hover:before {
    background: #090;
}
.ci span:before {
    top: 12px;
    left: -6px;
    width: 9px;
    height: 9px;
    border-width: 0 0 1px 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #e5e5e5;
    background: #fff;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
}
/*gggggg*/
    .cl:after {
    width: 5px;
    height: 5px;
    border: 3px solid #CCC;
    border-radius: 100px;
    margin: 10px 0 0 445px;
    background: #000;
}
.cl:hover:after {
    background: #090;
}
.cl span:after {
    top: 12px;
    left: 404px;
    width: 9px;
    height: 9px;
    border-width: 1px 1px 0 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #e5e5e5;
    background: #fff;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
}
​
</style>
    </head>

    <body style="overflow:hidden;">
    <div class="line">
      <div class="ci"><span>one</span></div>
      <div class="cl"><span>two</span></div>
      <div class="ci"><span>one</span></div>
      <div class="cl"><span>two</span></div>
      <div class="ci"><span>one</span></div>
      <div class="cl"><span>two</span></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redefined `.ci` and `.cl` to:

```css
.ci {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    clear: right;/*added*/
}

.cl {
    position: relative;
    /*text-align: right;*//*removed*/
    float: left;/*added*/
    clear: left;/*added*/
}
```

Changed `line div` and `.cl span:after` to:

```css
.line div {
    width: 396px;/*changed from 408px*/
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: solid 1px #B4BBCD;
    min-height: 35px;
    text-align: justify;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    list-style: none;
}

.line:before {
    width: 2px;/*changed from 3px*/
    top: -20px;
    bottom: -20px;
    background: #000;
}

.cl span:after {
    top: 12px;
    left: 392px;/*changed from 404px*/
    width: 9px;
    height: 9px;
    border-width: 1px 1px 0 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #e5e5e5;
    background: #fff;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
}​
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cdtHx/1/

Is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 8):

Check my example on Github https://gist.github.com/OzzyCzech/6240202

It's vertical timeline element are on two sides (left and right)

[image]

Comment: Great answer after a long time. @ozzyczech

Answer (score 0):

```css
.wrapper{
  max-width: 200px;
  border-right: 1px solid green;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
.wrapper .element{
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
  margin-top: -30px;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.wrapper .element:before{
  position: absolute;
  content:'';
  width: 20px;
  top: 10px;
  right: -15px;
  border-top: 1px solid red;
}
.wrapper .element:first-child{
  margin-top: 0;
}
.wrapper .element:nth-child(2n){
  margin-left: 110%;
}
.wrapper .element:nth-child(2n):before{
  right: auto;
  left: -15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="element">text text<p>text</p>texttext</div>
  <div class="element">text text<p>text</p>texttext</div>
  <div class="element">text text<p>text</p>texttext</div>
  <div class="element">text text<p>text</p>texttext</div>
  <div class="element">text text<p>text</p>texttext</div>
  <div class="element">text text<p>text</p>texttext</div>
</div>
```